# Boost Converter IC: Swap Decoupling Caps with Equivalent Parallel Capacitance

Tags: capacitor, circuit-design, decoupling-capacitor

I'm working with a Boost converter IC [MT3608] with the data sheet suggesting 22µF caps on both the input line [decoupling] and output lines [output filtering?]. As part of BOM consolidation though, I'm trying to remove these two caps since I don't use 22µF anywhere else.

Instead, I'm looking to use 2x 10µF caps which should have [*reasonably*] equivalent parallel capacitance as a 22µF. Theoretically, it should also have reduced equivalent series resistance since I'm using 2 caps instead of 1, making it perform better.

Would there be any downsides to swapping these caps out then? Presumeably, they don't serve some value-critical function and should be safe to swap with something close right?

[image]

Comment: Should be fine. Cap tolerance is like 5% at best anyways. Probably 10% or 20% Lower ESL too.

Comment: Thanks @DKNguyen, the caps I'm using are +/- 10%, so I expect the circuit not to be too sensitive. Wasn't sure if these served any other critical purpose than just plain filtering to warrant high tolerances to the spec.

Comment: You may place a third parallel cap, and only populate it if performance turns out to be marginal.